# Background color change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanna change the background color on a scroll, but I think that problem is I'm using Bootstrap. Can you help me? Any solutions? I'm almost sure it doesn't work because of Bootstrap. I can't type in data-color !important or in JavaScript. What can I do to overwrite the Bootstrap class?

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.bg');

function changeBackground(){
    const bottom= window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;

    sections.forEach(section => {
        sectionMiddle= section.offsetTop + (section.offsetHeight / 2);

        if(bottom >sectionMiddle){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = section.dataset.color;
        }
    });
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', changeBackground);
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-color: #9bc3f6;
    transition: background .8s;
}

.section1, .section2{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-   alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-CuOF+2SnTUfTwSZjCXf01h7uYhfOBuxIhGKPbfEJ3+FqH/s6cIFN9bGr1HmAg4fQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid section1 bg" data-color="yellow">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  
    <div class="container-fluid text-center section2 bg" data-color="blue">
    <h1>Hello World 2</h1>
  </div>
  
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-popRpmFF9JQgExhfw5tZT4I9/CI5e2QcuUZPOVXb1m7qUmeR2b50u+YFEYe1wgzy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There should be no problem adding `!important` tag behind the `background-color`.

Comment: Yes, in CSS. But the background color is dynamically changed with JavaScript. If I add !important behind the bg-color in CSS, it won't change to the next bg-color.

Comment: Your snippet works fine (FF)

Comment: Hahahahaha I see now, I made a typing mistake in my program. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't blame Bootstrap; the problem is always between the keyboard and the chair. Your snippet works fine. What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: Just a typing mistake. I wrote 'clss' instead of 'class'

Answer (score 0):

It's not a css best practice to put !important to override css rules, to override bootstrap css rules it's better to add extra tags in your selector :
for example:

```
``const sections = document.querySelectorAll('body .bg');``
```

or:

```
``const sections = document.querySelectorAll('html body .bg');``
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved the problem already. But anyway, thanks.